# Problem with using gnosis safe in fuji testnet

Tags: gnosis-safe

I have problems using gnosis safe in fuji testnet.
On this page https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/learn/safe-core-api/available-services
there is no corresponding url for connecting, only for Avalanche network.

I use this code to get pending transactions, but service returns "not found" error:

```js
const address = '0xCbCb5119c2239C4AeA74fBC91AEc3e9B1166Ef79';

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
    'https://api.avax-test.network/ext/C/rpc',
);
const owner1Signer = new ethers.Wallet(
    process.env.SERVICE_WALLET_SECRET_KEY,
    provider,
);
const ethAdapterOwner1 = new EthersAdapter({
    ethers,
    signerOrProvider: owner1Signer,
});
const txServiceUrl = 'https://safe-transaction-avalanche.safe.global/';
const safeService = new SafeServiceClient({
    txServiceUrl,
    ethAdapter: ethAdapterOwner1,
});
const { results } = await safeService.getPendingTransactions(address);
console.log(results);
```

I think this happen because i use 'https://safe-transaction-avalanche.safe.global/' url.
Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no service available for fuji testnet, you can run your own using https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure